# Keep only digits in a string

Tags: php, regex

Here is the `regex` which is removing characters and keeping only digits in a string. This working fine. Please read below examples which are not working for only one case - that is if user enters "4 four" so it can be converted to 44.

```
 //1
    //with out character 
    $amount = "44"; 
    $cleanedamount = preg_replace ( '/[^0-9]+/', '',  $amount);
    var_dump($cleanedamount);
    //2
    //digit prior
    $amount1 = "44usd"; 
    $cleanedamount1 = preg_replace ( '/[^0-9]+/', '',  $amount1);
    var_dump($cleanedamount1);

    //3
    //digit later
    $amount2 = "usd44"; 
    $cleanedamount2 = preg_replace ( '/[^0-9]+/', '',  $amount2);
    var_dump($cleanedamount2);

    //4
    //how to convert "4 four" to "44"
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/ynug9h)

Comment: You need to check first if the string contains a space, the split on the space. If each word matches a "number" (you can create an array of words > numbers), then do the replacement. Finally join the remaining string together and cast it to int.

Comment: What you mean by convert "4 four" to "44"? this is not a regex case!

Comment: Question title doesn't match with the nature of the problem.

Comment: @anubhava Please change according to your thoughts

Comment: @anubhava +1 , @Jamal what about `8 five` , should that be `85` ?

Comment: I think you can't match such values ? if you have limited values then you can match array or some like function.

Comment: @MahmoodRehman but there could be a shorter and smarter way, does PHP so limited or our logic limited  ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran yes

Comment: @rullof your suggestions are welcomed

Answer (score 2):

Try this : [Live Demo](https://eval.in/84312)

```
$input = "4 four five";
$numbers = array('0'=> 0, 'zero'=> 0, 'one'=> 1, 'two'=> 2, 'tree'=> 3, 'four'=> 4, 'five'=> 5, 'six'=> 6, 'seven'=> 7, 'eight' => 8, 'nine'=> 9);

$reg = '/[0-9]|zero|one|two|tree|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine/';
preg_match_all($reg, $input, $output);

$out = '';
foreach ($output[0] as $key=>$value){
 if (isset($numbers[$value])){
    $output[0][$key] = $numbers[$value];
    }
    $out = $out . $output[0][$key];
}

echo($out);
```

Comment: BTW are you still thinking 'this is not regex case' :P

Comment: @Jamal Sure as the main issue is converting names to digits!

Answer (score 1):

really you'd have to replace before with str_replace

```
//4
//how to convert "4 four" to "44"
$amount2 = "44 four"; 
$amount2=str_replace("four","4",$amount2);
$amount2=str_replace("five","5",$amount2);
...
$cleanedamount2 = preg_replace ( '/[^0-9]+/', '',  $amount2);
var_dump($cleanedamount2);
```

Comment: But this gonna son long

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious way is to use `str_replace` to replace the strings with numbers. For example...

```
$nums = [
    'one' => 1,
    'two' => 2,
    'three' => 3,
    // etc ...
];

$amount = str_replace(array_keys($nums), array_values($nums), $amount);
```

Comment: what about seventy nine etc ? How you could make array with all letters.

Comment: Obviously you would have to write something a little more advanced to support teens, tens, hundreds, thousands, etc. This answer isn't meant to be a complete solution, only to guide the OP in the right direction.

Comment: yeah but it didn't fully match what jamal wants.